# Dual boot Linux & Windows - Intel AX200 Wifi - Wifi not working nor appearing in rfkill on linux, but works in windows

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, intel, iwlwifi

I did a recent reinstall of both Windows 10 and Fedora 36 Linux where I installed Fedora Linux first then Windows 10. While wifi worked when installing Linux and in Windows, wifi stopped working on later bootups of the OS while still working fine in Windows. Things I observed & tried:

- `rfkill` would not show the wifi device
- double-checked the bios had WLAN turned on
- looking at the dmesg (via `journalctl --no-hostname -k > dmesg.txt` then `vim dmesg.txt`) revealed an error like `Nov 07 15:05:14 kernel: iwlwifi: probe of 0000:6c:00.0 failed with error -110`
- I had tried to update the firmware via `sudo dnf update iwlax2xx-firmware` but it was already up to date.
- I tried following the advice in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254766&p=2 and made a file of `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` with `options iwlmvm power_scheme=1` and rebooted, didn't change anything.

I feel like I've tried most advice, anything else to try?

(A sidebar: I had switched from Windows/Ubuntu dualboot to Windows/Fedora dualboot after having bluetooth issues after upgrading from ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438225/22-04-to-22-10-upgrade-bluetooth-no-longer-turns-on )

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get Wifi to work by doing the following:

- Turning off the computer.
- Booting back into windows, where wifi works.
- In Windows, turning wifi off.
- Reboot into Linux (Fedora).
- Observe Wifi is working (may need to enable it).

Answer inspired by advice on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=279069 . Doing similar might have resolved my bluetooth issues experienced previously in Ubuntu 22.10 as well.